# I (pipe) xargs issue with odd filenames (was: Redirection operator > in MacOS stopped working)

Tags: macos, unix, grep, pipe, operator-keyword

For some reason, pipe & redirection operators ('|' and '>') stopped working in my MacOS.
For years, I've been using commands like

```
find . -name "*.js" | xargs grep "import" > ../out.txt
```

to find string occurrences in a directory tree. But recently I'm getting following error:

```
grep: unrecognized option `--out-file'
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

Individually, commands

```
find . -name "*.js" > ../out.txt
```

and

```
grep "import" *.js > ../out.txt
```

are working just fine. So the problem is that somehow pipe '|' and redirection '>' stopped working together.
Any ideas?

I'm running Os X Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: Are you sure that one of the file found by `find` does not contains any *strange* pattern such `--out-file`... Change the title of your question, it is not a problem of redirection.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Baptiste, you are spot on!

Answer (score 2):

Some filenames can be recognized as grep's option (--out-file).
Just use -print0 option for find.

Like this:

```
find . -name "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "import" > ../out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

"find ... | xargs grep ..." operator combination is sensitive to the file names being passed. If a filename can be recognized as command's (grep in my case) option, the command will treat it as an option, not a filename.

Just for general information, the offending files were found inside "babel" node.js module.